# Standard Deviation Pooling with Keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a standard deviation pooling layer using keras. The idea is similar to implement a layer with a functionality similar to `AveragePooling1D`, but calculating standard deviation instead.

My first course of action was to try and implement this as a Lambda layer. It should take a 3d tensor such as (batch_size,time,features) and a stride integer (indicating the size of the window). It should return a tensor with shape (batch_size,time,features).

My implementation follows:

```python
import tensorflow
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense, TimeDistributed, Lambda, Input
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K

def stdev_pooling(inputs):
    data, stride = inputs

    stride = K.cast(stride, dtype='int32')

    print K.dtype(stride), K.dtype(data), '---'

    num_windows = K.shape(data)[1] / stride

    idxs = K.arange(num_windows) * stride

    windows = K.map_fn(lambda w: data[:, w: (w + stride), :], idxs, dtype=K.floatx())

    windows = K.permute_dimensions(windows, (1,0,2,3))

    stds = K.map_fn(lambda w: K.std(w, axis=1), windows)

    return stds

ipt = Input(shape=(None,10))
d = TimeDistributed(Dense(10))(ipt)
out = Lambda(stdev_pooling)([d,K.variable(20, dtype='int32', name='stride_var')])

m = keras.Model(inputs=ipt, outputs=out)
x = np.arange(1000).reshape(1,-1,10)
m.predict(x).shape
```

However, my output (which shows the data types for both the stride and the data tensors, in this order) is this:

```
int32 float32 ---
float32 float32 ---
```

And the stack trace is this:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
          1 ipt = Input(shape=(None,10))
          2 d = TimeDistributed(Dense(10))(ipt)
    ----> 3 out = Lambda(stdev_pooling)([d,K.variable(20, dtype='int32', name='stride_var')])

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.pyc in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
        472             if all([s is not None
        473                     for s in to_list(input_shape)]):
    --> 474                 output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
        475             else:
        476                 if isinstance(input_shape, list):

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.pyc in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
        643                 if isinstance(input_shape, list):
        644                     xs = [K.placeholder(shape=shape) for shape in input_shape]
    --> 645                     x = self.call(xs)
        646                 else:
        647                     x = K.placeholder(shape=input_shape)

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.pyc in call(self, inputs, mask)
        680         if has_arg(self.function, 'mask'):
        681             arguments['mask'] = mask
    --> 682         return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
        683 
        684     def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):

     in stdev_pooling(inputs)
          5     print K.dtype(stride), K.dtype(data), '---'
          6 
    ----> 7     num_windows = K.shape(data)[1] / stride
          8 
          9     idxs = K.arange(num_windows-1) * stride

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.pyc in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
        848     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
        849       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
    --> 850         return func(x, y, name=name)
        851       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
        852         try:

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.pyc in _div_python2(x, y, name)
        972   with ops.name_scope(name, "div", [x, y]) as name:
        973     x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, name="x")
    --> 974     y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, name="y", dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)
        975     x_dtype = x.dtype.base_dtype
        976     y_dtype = y.dtype.base_dtype

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
        996       name=name,
        997       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
    --> 998       as_ref=False)
        999 
       1000 

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
       1092 
       1093     if ret is None:
    -> 1094       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
       1095 
       1096     if ret is NotImplemented:

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
        929     raise ValueError(
        930         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
    --> 931         (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
        932   return t
        933 

    ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("lambda_9/Placeholder_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)'
```

Interestingly, as far as I understand, it says that the `stride` variable is a `float32`, which shoud be converted to `int32`, although it was declared an `int32` variable `K.variable(20, dtype='int32', name='stride_var')`.

What is wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As @BlackBear suggested, I added an explicit cast to stride and it seems to have solved part of the problem:

```
def stdev_pooling(inputs):
    data, stride = inputs

    stride = K.cast(stride, dtype='int32')

    print K.dtype(stride), K.dtype(data), '---'

    num_windows = K.shape(data)[1] / stride

    idxs = K.arange(num_windows) * stride

    windows = K.map_fn(lambda w: data[:, w: (w + stride), :], idxs, dtype=K.floatx())

    windows = K.permute_dimensions(windows, (1,0,2,3))

    stds = K.map_fn(lambda w: K.std(w, axis=1), windows)

    return stds
```

output:

```
int32 float32 ---
int32 float32 ---
```

However, now I have a new error that I have no idea where it comes from!

Here is the stack trace:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
          3 x = np.arange(2000).reshape(2,-1,10)
          4 
    ----> 5 m = keras.Model(inputs=ipt, outputs=out)
          6 
          7 m.predict(x).shape

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
         89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
         90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
    ---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
         92         wrapper._original_function = func
         93         return wrapper

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         91                 'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
         92             # Graph network
    ---> 93             self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
         94         else:
         95             # Subclassed network

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name)
        235         # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
        236         nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, layers_by_depth = _map_graph_network(
    --> 237             self.inputs, self.outputs)
        238         self._network_nodes = nodes
        239         self._nodes_by_depth = nodes_by_depth

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
       1351                   layer=layer,
       1352                   node_index=node_index,
    -> 1353                   tensor_index=tensor_index)
       1354 
       1355     for node in reversed(nodes_in_decreasing_depth):

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
       1338             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
       1339             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
    -> 1340                       node_index, tensor_index)
       1341 
       1342         finished_nodes.add(node)

    /home/juliano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
       1310             ValueError: if a cycle is detected.
       1311         """
    -> 1312         node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
       1313 
       1314         # Prevent cycles.

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

**EDIT**: I've updated my stdev_pooling function and it now returns the correct output. However, I'm still having the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'` error...

Comment: Seems like keras calls your function twice: the first time `stride` is an `int32`, but the second time it is a `float32`. I cannot explain why this happens, but adding an explicit cast to `int32` could help

Comment: Yup! It seems like so. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @JulianoFoleiss Not related to the error you get: are you sure your implementation is correct? Window size and stride are two different things and I don't see any variable representing window size in your code?

Comment: @today You are right. In this case I am considering that window size == stride, in other words there's no overlap between windows.

Comment: @BlackBear I added the explicit cast to int32 right after the beginning of the function and now the error is gone. Thanks! The fact that the function is called twice is interesting. However, now I have another error. I'll edit the question accordingly. Take a look if you want =D

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've fixed it. I'll put an answer later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling a bit more with the code and reading about how keras interacts with tensorflow (in many different places, including the source code for tensorflow and keras) I figured out what was wrong.

First of all, here's a minimal working example of what I wanted to do:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense, TimeDistributed, Lambda, Input
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K


def stdev_pooling(inputs, stride):

    data = inputs

    padding = K.shape(data)[1] % stride

    data = K.switch(padding > 0, K.temporal_padding(data, padding=(0,stride-padding)), data )

    num_windows = K.shape(data)[1] / stride

    idxs = K.arange(num_windows) * stride

    windows = K.map_fn(lambda w: data[:, w: (w + stride), :], idxs, dtype=K.floatx())

    windows = K.permute_dimensions(windows, (1,0,2,3))

    stds = K.map_fn(lambda w: K.std(w, axis=1), windows)

    return stds

ipt = Input(shape=(None,10))
d = TimeDistributed(Dense(10))(ipt)
#stride is an argument to stdev_pooling, not a signal coming from
#a previous layer. Thus it must be passed in the `arguments`
#dictionary of the `Lambda` layer.
out = Lambda(stdev_pooling, arguments={'stride':15})(d)

x = np.arange(2000).reshape(2,-1,10)    
m = keras.Model(inputs=ipt, outputs=out)    
y = m.predict(x)
print y
print y.shape
```

The problem stemmed from the line `out = Lambda(stdev_pooling)([d,K.variable(20, dtype='int32', name='stride_var')])` in the previous code.

When a signal (such as K.variable(...)) is provided as input to the Lambda layer, keras expects it to be connected to an Input layer. Thus, the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'`.

The solution was simply to provide the stride argument through the `arguments` dictionary of the Lambda layer constructor:

`out = Lambda(stdev_pooling, arguments={'stride':15})(d)`

I hope this code helps everyone trying to build some sort of pooling layer in keras. When I have some time I shall write it as a proper Pooling Layer. For now, this Lambda version should do.